# FOSUserBundle : access session var in a custom email

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am customizing the confirmation email sent after user registration.
My problem is that I can't access session vars in the email template.

Here is my code (similar to FOSUser documentation) :

```
{# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/User/confirmation.email.twig #}

{% block subject %}Confirmation{% endblock %}

{% block body_text %}
{% autoescape false %}
Hello {{ user.username }} !

Your locale is : {{ app.session.locale }}

Click on the following link to confirm your registration : {{ confirmationUrl }}

Greetings,
the Acme team
{% endautoescape %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body_html %}
{% include 'AcmeDemoBundle:User:confirmation_email.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

The following line returns an exception :

```
Your locale is : {{ app.session.locale }}
```

Exception :

```
Variable "app" does not exist in ...
```

How can I access session var from this template ?

I also need to access config parameters (from parameters.ini).
My parameters are already in global Twig access, but no way to access them in this template.

Many thanks for your help !
A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TwigSwiftMailer](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Mailer/TwigSwiftMailer.php#L36) class only expose `User` entity and confirmation url to the template. You have to extend the class and modify the methods. Then create the service and set as default mailer. You can check [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/mailer.xml#L27) for service definition.

**Edit:**

Sample implementation would be

The class .

```
//namespace declaration

class MySwiftMailer extends TwigSwiftMailer
{
    private $container;

    /**
     * @param Symofony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInerface   $container
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }


    public function sendConfirmationEmailMessage(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $template = $this->parameters['template']['confirmation'];
        $url = $this->router->generate('fos_user_registration_confirm', array('token' => $user->getConfirmationToken()), true);
        $context = array(
            'user' => $user,
            'container' => $this->container,
            'session' => $this->container->get('request')->getSession(), // expose session
            'confirmationUrl' => $url
        );

        $this->sendMessage($template, $context, $this->parameters['from_email']['confirmation'], $user->getEmail());
    }

    // implement sendResettingEmailMessage() in same way
}
```

Service declaration. Create a class named `mailer.xml` in your bundles `Resources/config` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>

        <service id="fos_user.mailer.my_swift_mailer" class="FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\TwigSwiftMailer" >
            <argument type="service" id="mailer" />
            <argument type="service" id="router" />
            <argument type="service" id="twig" />
            <argument type="collection">
                <argument key="template" type="collection">
                    <argument key="confirmation">%fos_user.registration.confirmation.template%</argument>
                    <argument key="resetting">%fos_user.resetting.email.template%</argument>
                </argument>
                <argument key="from_email" type="collection">
                    <argument key="confirmation">%fos_user.registration.confirmation.from_email%</argument>
                    <argument key="resetting">%fos_user.resetting.email.from_email%</argument>
                </argument>
            </argument>

            <call method="setContainer">
                <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
            </call>

        </service>

    </services>

</container>
```

To include the `loader.xml` you have to include following lines in `load` method of `YourBundle/DependencyInjection/YourBundleExtension.php`

```
$xmlLoader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
$xmlLoader->load("mailer.xml");
```

And in `app/config.yml` set the mailer.

```
# app/config/config.yml

fos_user:
    # ...
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.my_swift_mailer
```

Now in your template you can do `{{ session.get('var') }}` or `{{ container.getParameter('any_param') }}`

Comment: Hi, it sounds like a good solution but will I be able to access 'session' or 'config parameters' (from parameters.ini) in this extended class ?

Comment: Yes if you inject `@service_container`.

Comment: And `@request` to get current session.

Comment: wow... thanks a lot, I'm gonna try this today and come back to tell you if everything is ok !

Comment: Everything is ok ! Thanks a lot again !

Answer (score 0):

with

```
$session = $ this->get("session");
```

Have the same as app.session

So if you want you can send $session by RenderView()